# MTKView (or CAMetalLayer + CVDisplayLink) stuttering in fullscreen

Tags: macos, metal

I'm rendering Metal on macOS, and have found that I can't display stable 60 Hz in full screen on a MacBook Pro M2 Max, using either MTKView, or CAMetalLayer directly.

Frame rate oscillates between too slow and too fast.

[image: Metal Performance HUD showing frame rate oscillation]

There is visible (micro-)stuttering (try rendering a black bar on white ground that moves steadily across the screen), and the Metal Performance HUD shows the inconsistent frame updates as well.

I've tried adjusting ProMotion system settings, as well as combinations of preferredFramesPerSecond and displaySyncEnabled to no avail.

I've first noticed the problem with MTKView, but have also tried using CVDisplayLink with CAMetalLayer, same issue.

There seems to be something going on between the displayLink and the backend of CAMetalLayer, where the timing gets confused.

note this happens ONLY in fullscreen mode. And while you hover the mouse over the OS menu bar, or show the CMD+Tab UI, in other words: while other UI elements are rendered on top of the full screen view, the issue temporarily subsides.

it does NOT happen on my 2020 Intel Macbook Air. Only on the M2 Macbook Pro.

Just me, or everyone? Am I holding it wrong? I can't find anything about this on the web.
If it's an OS issue with this hardware, we can hope for Apple to update it. But I came here to ask: Can I implement the update timing in a way to circumvent the issue?

Here is some minimal code. Doesn't render anything, just presenting the drawable is enough to trigger the problem.

```
#import <Metal/Metal.h>
#import <MetalKit/MetalKit.h>

@interface ViewController() <MTKViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet MTKView *mtkView;
@property (nonatomic) id<MTLDevice> device;
@property (nonatomic) id<MTLCommandQueue> commandQueue;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
    _mtkView.device = _device;
    _mtkView.preferredFramesPerSecond = 60;
    _mtkView.delegate = self;
    _commandQueue = [_device newCommandQueue];
}

- (void)drawInMTKView:(MTKView *)view {
    MTLRenderPassDescriptor *viewRPD = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor;
    if(viewRPD) {
        id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [_commandQueue commandBuffer];
        [commandBuffer presentDrawable:view.currentDrawable];
        [commandBuffer commit];
    }
}

- (void)mtkView:(MTKView *)view drawableSizeWillChange:(CGSize)size { }

@end
```

[a slo-mo video showing it (youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-YPRlnTc2K0) - note how the video starts with mouse hovering on title bar, no stuttering. after hiding the title bar, the white line starts to misbehave, and you can see the pace oscillation in the performance HUD graph as well.

Comment: I'd recommend filing a Feedback report with Apple: https://feedbackassistant.apple.com

Comment: I did, and also installed Sonoma beta on an extra volume, where the issue does not occur.

Comment: Can you please provide a video that demonstrates this issue.

Comment: post edited with a video link.

Comment: I have a feeling there is an inconsistency with device screen refreshrates. CVDisplayLink is unable to sync properly. @Jakob curious if you have any new findings?

Comment: well, on Sonoma it's mostly not broken on the following modes (ProMotion enabled && MTKView render at 120Hz) || (ProMotion disabled && render at 60 Hz) -- if setting .preferredFramesPerSecond to 60 while ProMotion is enabled for example, it still gets wonky.

Comment: I am getting the same experience with MTKView with preferredFramesPerSecond = 60 and present(drawable, afterMinimumDuration: 1.0/60) when the app in full screen mode *only*. It does work correctly when the app is not maximised, or even when it's in full screen but you drag the mouse to the top to reveal window title, then it becomes smooth. GPU load is minimal. Struggling with this to no avail. MacBook Pro M2 Max.

Answer (score 0):

My answer doesn't include code, but I believe it will be helpful as I spent 3 days before I figured it out.

You need to use a semaphore to control access to the "in-flight" frames, and the maximum of the "in-flight" frames should be equal to 3 (because MTKView uses triple buffering).

To find out how to do this correctly is easy. Start a new "Game" project in xcode, and select the framework "Metal" (not "SceneKit" or "SpriteKit"), and you can skip tests generation. Then you can find the relevant code in the "Renderer.swift" file (or whatever language you selected).

I commented out all the "cube rotation" rendering in the default project, and just left the drawable presentation. The glitch disappeared at 60 FPS when the window is maximised (or not). Additionally I tried rendering the full video sample with graphics at 120 FPS (by setting preferredFrameRate on the view), and it works marvellously. You can enable metal information display in the options to see that there is no fluctuation if frame rate. Well, there is, but not glitchy anymore.

I'm using MacBook Pro M2.

Comment: I just started from the macOS game template, without any modification, and also with removing all the rendering, and it acts the same as before for me, frame rate still oscillating. the semaphore does not seem to make a difference. I think we just all upgrade to Sonoma at some point and it's history ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Finally, Sonoma came out and all the problems went away! I guess I'll have to release my app with minimum MacOS version requirement of 14.0. Can't let the people see what happens on <14...